# Quick Return on StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, footer, onscrolllistener, staggered-gridview

I recently stumbled upon a [QuickReturn Library specified for Grid View](https://github.com/felipecsl/QuickReturn/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/felipecsl/quickreturn/library).

Importing the library just worked fine but as testing i discovered following error.

To visualize my problem i uploaded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK1wuyXm9gU) on Youtube. The animation of the footer just works fine. But as u scroll through that specific item the footer quickly appears and reappears without any reason.

I guess the problem is caused by the fact that I'm using a library specified for GridView on Etsy's StaggeredGridView. Since i don't know which of the library's classes are responsible for the problem I don't post any code. Is there anything to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how I solved this in the code below. This a custom `OnScrollListener` for a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`.

You can see more examples here : https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn

#### QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment.java

```
public class QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

    // region Member Variables
    private String[] mValues;
    private QuickReturnAnimationType mQuickReturnAnimationType;
    private String mLayoutManagerType;

    @InjectView(R.id.rv)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @InjectView(R.id.quick_return_tv)
    TextView mQuickReturnTextView;
    // endregion

    // region Constructors
    public static QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment newInstance(Bundle extras) {
        QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment fragment = new QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment();
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragment.setArguments(extras);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment newInstance() {
        QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment fragment = new QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public QuickReturnFooterRecyclerViewFragment() {
    }
    // endregion

    // region Lifecycle Methods
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            mQuickReturnAnimationType = QuickReturnAnimationType.valueOf(getArguments().getString("quick_return_animation_type"));
            mLayoutManagerType = getArguments().getString("layout_manager");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview_quick_return_footer, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

        if(mLayoutManagerType.equals("linear")){
            CountriesLinearLayoutAdapter countriesLinearLayoutAdapter = new CountriesLinearLayoutAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(mValues));

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(countriesLinearLayoutAdapter);
        } else if(mLayoutManagerType.equals("grid")) {
            CountriesGridLayoutAdapter countriesGridLayoutAdapter = new CountriesGridLayoutAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(mValues));

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacesItemDecoration(QuickReturnUtils.dp2px(getActivity(), 8)));

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(countriesGridLayoutAdapter);
        }

        int footerHeight = getActivity().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.footer_height);

        QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener scrollListener;
        SpeedyQuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener scrollListener2;

        switch (mQuickReturnAnimationType){
            case TRANSLATION_SIMPLE:
                if(mLayoutManagerType.equals("grid")){
                    scrollListener = new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .minFooterTranslation(footerHeight)
                            .columnCount(2)
                            .build();
                } else {
                    scrollListener = new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .minFooterTranslation(footerHeight)
                            .build();
                }
                mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
                break;
            case TRANSLATION_SNAP:
                if(mLayoutManagerType.equals("grid")){
                    scrollListener = new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .minFooterTranslation(footerHeight)
                            .columnCount(2)
                            .isSnappable(true)
                            .build();
                } else {
                    scrollListener = new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .minFooterTranslation(footerHeight)
                            .isSnappable(true)
                            .build();
                }
                mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
                break;
            case TRANSLATION_ANTICIPATE_OVERSHOOT:
                if(mLayoutManagerType.equals("grid")){
                    scrollListener2 = new SpeedyQuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(getActivity(), QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .columnCount(2)
                            .build();
                } else {
                    scrollListener2 = new SpeedyQuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(getActivity(), QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .build();
                }
                mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener2);
                break;
            default:
                if(mLayoutManagerType.equals("grid")){
                    scrollListener = new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .minFooterTranslation(footerHeight)
                            .columnCount(2)
                            .build();
                } else {
                    scrollListener = new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.Builder(QuickReturnViewType.FOOTER)
                            .footer(mQuickReturnTextView)
                            .minFooterTranslation(footerHeight)
                            .build();
                }
                mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ButterKnife.reset(this);
    }
    // endregion

}
```

#### QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener.java

```
public class QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    // region Member Variables
    private final QuickReturnViewType mQuickReturnViewType;
    private final View mHeader;
    private final int mMinHeaderTranslation;
    private final View mFooter;
    private final int mMinFooterTranslation;
    private final int mColumnCount;
    private final boolean mIsSnappable; // Can Quick Return view snap into place?

    private int mPrevScrollY = 0;
    private int mHeaderDiffTotal = 0;
    private int mFooterDiffTotal = 0;
    private List<RecyclerView.OnScrollListener> mExtraOnScrollListenerList = new ArrayList<>();
    // endregion

    // region Constructors
    private QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener(Builder builder) {
        mQuickReturnViewType = builder.mQuickReturnViewType;
        mHeader = builder.mHeader;
        mMinHeaderTranslation = builder.mMinHeaderTranslation;
        mFooter = builder.mFooter;
        mMinFooterTranslation = builder.mMinFooterTranslation;
        mColumnCount = builder.mColumnCount;
        mIsSnappable = builder.mIsSnappable;
    }
    // endregion


    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        // apply another list' s on scroll listener
        for (RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener : mExtraOnScrollListenerList) {
          listener.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && mIsSnappable) {

            int midHeader = -mMinHeaderTranslation/2;
            int midFooter = mMinFooterTranslation/2;

            switch (mQuickReturnViewType) {
                case HEADER:
                    if (-mHeaderDiffTotal > 0 && -mHeaderDiffTotal < midHeader) {
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeader, "translationY", mHeader.getTranslationY(), 0);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = 0;
                    } else if (-mHeaderDiffTotal < -mMinHeaderTranslation && -mHeaderDiffTotal >= midHeader) {
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeader, "translationY", mHeader.getTranslationY(), mMinHeaderTranslation);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = mMinHeaderTranslation;
                    }
                    break;
                case FOOTER:
                    if (-mFooterDiffTotal > 0 && -mFooterDiffTotal < midFooter) { // slide up
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFooter, "translationY", mFooter.getTranslationY(), 0);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mFooterDiffTotal = 0;
                    } else if (-mFooterDiffTotal < mMinFooterTranslation && -mFooterDiffTotal >= midFooter) { // slide down
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFooter, "translationY", mFooter.getTranslationY(), mMinFooterTranslation);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mFooterDiffTotal = -mMinFooterTranslation;
                    }
                    break;
                case BOTH:
                    if (-mHeaderDiffTotal > 0 && -mHeaderDiffTotal < midHeader) {
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeader, "translationY", mHeader.getTranslationY(), 0);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = 0;
                    } else if (-mHeaderDiffTotal < -mMinHeaderTranslation && -mHeaderDiffTotal >= midHeader) {
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeader, "translationY", mHeader.getTranslationY(), mMinHeaderTranslation);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = mMinHeaderTranslation;
                    }

                    if (-mFooterDiffTotal > 0 && -mFooterDiffTotal < midFooter) { // slide up
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFooter, "translationY", mFooter.getTranslationY(), 0);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mFooterDiffTotal = 0;
                    } else if (-mFooterDiffTotal < mMinFooterTranslation && -mFooterDiffTotal >= midFooter) { // slide down
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFooter, "translationY", mFooter.getTranslationY(), mMinFooterTranslation);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mFooterDiffTotal = -mMinFooterTranslation;
                    }
                    break;
                case TWITTER:
                    if (-mHeaderDiffTotal > 0 && -mHeaderDiffTotal < midHeader) {
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeader, "translationY", mHeader.getTranslationY(), 0);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = 0;
                    } else if (-mHeaderDiffTotal < -mMinHeaderTranslation && -mHeaderDiffTotal >= midHeader) {
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeader, "translationY", mHeader.getTranslationY(), mMinHeaderTranslation);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = mMinHeaderTranslation;
                    }

                    if (-mFooterDiffTotal > 0 && -mFooterDiffTotal < midFooter) { // slide up
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFooter, "translationY", mFooter.getTranslationY(), 0);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mFooterDiffTotal = 0;
                    } else if (-mFooterDiffTotal < mMinFooterTranslation && -mFooterDiffTotal >= midFooter) { // slide down
                        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mFooter, "translationY", mFooter.getTranslationY(), mMinFooterTranslation);
                        anim.setDuration(100);
                        anim.start();
                        mFooterDiffTotal = -mMinFooterTranslation;
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        // apply extra on scroll listener
        for (RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener : mExtraOnScrollListenerList) {
          listener.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }

        int scrollY = QuickReturnUtils.getScrollY(recyclerView, mColumnCount);
//        Log.d("", "onScrolled() : scrollY - "+scrollY);
        int diff = mPrevScrollY - scrollY;
//        Log.d("", "onScrolled() : diff - "+diff);

        if(diff != 0){
            switch (mQuickReturnViewType){
                case HEADER:
                    if(diff < 0){ // scrolling down
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = Math.max(mHeaderDiffTotal + diff, mMinHeaderTranslation);
                    } else { // scrolling up
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = Math.min(Math.max(mHeaderDiffTotal + diff, mMinHeaderTranslation), 0);
                    }

                    mHeader.setTranslationY(mHeaderDiffTotal);
                    break;
                case FOOTER:
                    if(diff < 0){ // scrolling down
                        mFooterDiffTotal = Math.max(mFooterDiffTotal + diff, -mMinFooterTranslation);
                    } else { // scrolling up
                        mFooterDiffTotal = Math.min(Math.max(mFooterDiffTotal + diff, -mMinFooterTranslation), 0);
                    }

                    mFooter.setTranslationY(-mFooterDiffTotal);
                    break;
                case BOTH:
                    if(diff < 0){ // scrolling down
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = Math.max(mHeaderDiffTotal + diff, mMinHeaderTranslation);
                        mFooterDiffTotal = Math.max(mFooterDiffTotal + diff, -mMinFooterTranslation);
                    } else { // scrolling up
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = Math.min(Math.max(mHeaderDiffTotal + diff, mMinHeaderTranslation), 0);
                        mFooterDiffTotal = Math.min(Math.max(mFooterDiffTotal + diff, -mMinFooterTranslation), 0);
                    }

                    mHeader.setTranslationY(mHeaderDiffTotal);
                    mFooter.setTranslationY(-mFooterDiffTotal);
                    break;
                case TWITTER:
                    if(diff < 0){ // scrolling down
                        if(scrollY > -mMinHeaderTranslation)
                            mHeaderDiffTotal = Math.max(mHeaderDiffTotal + diff, mMinHeaderTranslation);

                        if(scrollY > mMinFooterTranslation)
                            mFooterDiffTotal = Math.max(mFooterDiffTotal + diff, -mMinFooterTranslation);
                    } else { // scrolling up
                        mHeaderDiffTotal = Math.min(Math.max(mHeaderDiffTotal + diff, mMinHeaderTranslation), 0);
                        mFooterDiffTotal = Math.min(Math.max(mFooterDiffTotal + diff, -mMinFooterTranslation), 0);
                    }

                    mHeader.setTranslationY(mHeaderDiffTotal);
                    mFooter.setTranslationY(-mFooterDiffTotal);
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        mPrevScrollY = scrollY;
    }

    // region Helper Methods
    public void registerExtraOnScrollListener(RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener) {
        mExtraOnScrollListenerList.add(listener);
    }
    // endregion

    // region Inner Classes

    public static class Builder {
        // Required parameters
        private final QuickReturnViewType mQuickReturnViewType;

        // Optional parameters - initialized to default values
        private View mHeader = null;
        private int mMinHeaderTranslation = 0;
        private View mFooter = null;
        private int mMinFooterTranslation = 0;
        private int mColumnCount = 1;
        private boolean mIsSnappable = false;

        public Builder(QuickReturnViewType quickReturnViewType) {
            mQuickReturnViewType = quickReturnViewType;
        }

        public Builder header(View header){
            mHeader = header;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder minHeaderTranslation(int minHeaderTranslation){
            mMinHeaderTranslation = minHeaderTranslation;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder footer(View footer){
            mFooter = footer;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder minFooterTranslation(int minFooterTranslation){
            mMinFooterTranslation = minFooterTranslation;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder columnCount(int columnCount){
            mColumnCount = columnCount;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder isSnappable(boolean isSnappable){
            mIsSnappable = isSnappable;
            return this;
        }

        public QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener build() {
            return new QuickReturnRecyclerViewOnScrollListener(this);
        }
    }

    // endregion
}
```